# Message: Undefined property: Material_model::$load Filename: libraries/Form_validation.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am a newbie to Codeigniter and trying to build a service registration page. Not just the page but the whole website has this error.

```
$autoload['model'] = array('User_model','Material_model');
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','form_validation');


class services extends CI_Controller {
public function service1()
{

  $this->form_validation->set_rules('type','Type',trim|required);
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('area','Area',trim|required);
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('quantity','Quantity',trim|required);
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('details','Details',trim|required);
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Name',trim|required);
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('number','Number',trim|required);
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('location','Location',trim|required);
if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
            $data['main_view']="page_view";
$this->load->view('layouts/main',$data);
} else{
$this->user_model->create_user();
redirect('/');
}
```

I'm getting this error in user model from material model. Th

Comment: You don't show where you're calling `$this->material_model->load`, so you haven't really given us enough here. Also, class names should begin with an upper case - CI can be really picky about case, I seem to recall (particularly in filenames).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should load the model in your parent construct.
For example:

```
class services extends CI_Controller {
  function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('your_directory_model, 'your_initialize_model');
  }
}
```

And then, if you want to use your model. you can build code like i write below in your method.

```
$this->your_initialize_model->your_model_method();
```

Comment: Loading the model in the constructor or before you need the model's method or in autoload... it doesn't really make a difference. My general rule of thumb is if it is used more than a couple of times in the controller, load the model in the constructor, otherwise load it at the top of the controller function. If I use the model alot, autoload it. Either way, `services` should be `Services` and saved as `Services.php` ... CI is picky about controller capitalization both in the name of the file and in the class declaration.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry, I think you write the `$autoload['model'] = array('User_model','Material_model');` in your controller.
so, what is your problem actually? I cannot understand your question now.

Comment: Oh my god, I am sorry.